# How can I start a shell if booting fails?

Tags: boot, systemd

During boot I am looking for a way to get access to a terminal if the boot fails.

As is happening to me in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1662772).

Answer (score 2):

According to this document, the clever people who ever they are have already put in place a rescue console

https://wiki.debian.org/systemd

```
$ systemctl enable debug-shell.service  
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/debug-shell.service → /lib/systemd/system/debug-shell.service.
```

This is then activated on tty9.
You can get to by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>[left/right]</kbd> to cycle to the correct tty as need.

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/debug-shell.service 
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Early root shell on /dev/tty9 FOR DEBUGGING ONLY
Documentation=man:sushell(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty9

[Service]
Environment=TERM=linux
ExecStart=/bin/bash
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty9
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
# bash ignores SIGTERM
KillSignal=SIGHUP

# Unset locale for the console getty since the console has problems
# displaying some internationalized messages.
Environment=LANG= LANGUAGE= LC_CTYPE= LC_NUMERIC= LC_TIME= LC_COLLATE= LC_MONETARY= LC_MESSAGES= LC_PAPER= LC_NAME= LC_ADDRESS= LC_TELEPHONE= LC_MEASUREMENT= LC_IDENTIFICATION=

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```